# How to set variable's value inside if block when value includes parenthesis

Tags: windows, batch

I am having problem in setting value inside if block. Please consider the following code :

**\mytool.bat**

```
@echo off
if not "%adder%" == "" (
    set val=%val%;%adder%
) else (
    echo please set adder first
)
echo value="%val%"
```

Now when I run the following through cmd :

```
set adder=a(bc)d
mytool
```

It gives me error i.e.

```
d was unexpected at this time.
```

**On the other hand following is working**

```
set adder=abcd
mytool
```

with output `value=";abcd"`
I want the similar behaviour even when `adder` have parenthesis.
I also tried [this](https://superuser.com/a/919767/366649). But it only persist changes in variable val inside the batch.

Comment: As far as I can see, the accepted answer in David Postill's link in your previous question deals adequately with the  problem. Why didn't it work for you?

Comment: Why don't you get rid of the parentheses and use `goto` instead? Not exactly neat, but it bypasses the problem.

Comment: @AFH Yes, goto could do it. but I would have to change so much code in my real batch to implement it. And actually David's this answer solved it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### How do I set a variable's value inside an if block when value includes parentheses?

If the variable value contains a parenthesis `(` or `)` you need to quote the `set` right hand side expression in the batch file `set "val=%val%;%adder%"`

test.cmd:

```
@echo off
if not "%adder%" == "" (
    set "val=%val%;%adder%"
) else (
    echo please set adder first
)
echo value=%val%
```

output:

```
C:\test>set val=somevalue

C:\test>set adder=a(bc)d

C:\test>test
value=somevalue;a(bc)d
```

---

**"Because the value of val not persist outside the batch file"**

Not true.

```
C:\test>set | findstr val
val=somevalue;a(bc)d
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.

Answer (score 0):

my suggestion is :

```
if (condition_TRUE) goto goodbye_parenthesis_BEGIN

goto goodbye_parenthesis_END  ----- line when previous condition is FALSE ----
:goodbye_parenthesis_BEGIN ----- line when previous condition is TRUE ----

...
variable treatment
...

:goodbye_parenthesis_END
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on this a little more?